# Vue.js 2 - v-model on component

Tags: vuejs2, vue.js

I have the following component:

```
Vue.component('test-component',{ 

    template: `<div>
        {{value}}
        <button on:click="updateValue();">update</button>
    </div>`,

    props: ['value'],

    methods: {
        updateValue(){
            this.$emit('input', this.value + "X");
        }
    }
});
```

Instantiated as follows, (bound to a data variable 'testValue):

```
<test-component v-model="testValue"></test-component>
```

The code is intended to add an 'X' at the end of the bound value upon clicking the button.

My intention is to create a reusable component that can be bound to data in its enclosing components, in order to for example create custom form inputs.

It does not work - the emit does not seem to do anything. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [v-on](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on) instead of just `on` in following line, which will bound the vue methods to the button:

```
template: `<div>
    {{value}}
    <button v-on:click="updateValue();">update</button>
</div>`,
```

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fr6avL10/).